# Get 2 dates from within brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement in SQL Server to get the 2 dates inside the brackets

Example: Billing for(1 Aug 2020 - 30 Oct 2020)

Expected to have this in two columns:

```
Fromdate         Todate
01/08/2020       30/10/2020
```

Select substring to get the value but not sure how to do both in one query.

Comment: What's your question about this? Please share more details, like the query you are using. Also, add proper tags

Comment: And please state which locale you use if you use date formats other than ISO 8601. Dates are a real source of confusion.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Convert` and `Concat`:

```sql
Select *, 
Concat(
    'Billing for(', 
    Convert(VarChar(50), Fromdate, 106), 
    ' - ', 
    Convert(VarChar(50), Todate, 106),
    ')') As Period 

From YourTable
```

The reverse operation:

```sql
Select 
    Convert(DateTime, SubString([Field Name], PatIndex('%(%', [Field Name]) + 1, 11)) As Fromdate,
    Convert(DateTime, SubString([Field Name], PatIndex('%)%', [Field Name]) - 11, 11)) As Todate
```

Comment: I *think* OP is saying they want the reverse, i.e. given the string with dates and brackets, extract the dates.

Comment: @DaleK: Yes, I guess I read it backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution based on *tokenization* via XML and XQuery.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards due to dependency on the `CONCAT_WS()` function. If you are on some earlier version of SQL Server, it   could be replaced with the `CONCAT()` function.

As an intermediate result, the t(c) contains the following XML:

```
<root>
  <r>1</r>
  <r>Aug</r>
  <r>2020</r>
  <r>-</r>
  <r>30</r>
  <r>Oct</r>
  <r>2020</r>
</root>
```

After that it is simple XQuery extracting date parts based on position and compose real dates.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(100) = 'Billing for(1 Aug 2020 - 30 Oct 2020)'
    , @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT @input AS input
        , CHARINDEX('(', @input) AS [start]
        , CHARINDEX(')', @input) AS [end]
)
SELECT rs.input, c
    , TRY_CAST(CONCAT_WS('-'
        , c.value('(/root/r[3]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(4)')
        , c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)')
        , c.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(2)')) AS DATE) AS FromDate
    , TRY_CAST(CONCAT_WS('-'
        , c.value('(/root/r[7]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(4)')
        , c.value('(/root/r[6]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)')
        , c.value('(/root/r[5]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(2)')) AS DATE) AS ToDate
FROM rs
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(SUBSTRING(input, [start]+1, [end] - [start]-1), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c);
```

**Output**

| input | FromDate | ToDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Billing for(1 Aug 2020 - 30 Oct 2020) | 2020-08-01 | 2020-10-30 |